# axios.put() function does not update SQL Server Database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a simple react page connected with a `Node.js` backend. Now after I've connected the React front end page's user inputs with the `axios.put()` function to update it does not update in the database neither give me any error. I'm logging all outputs to the console and to me all seems like working good.

My code : `App.js`

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [orderNumber, setOrderNumber] = useState(0);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/event/${orderNumber}`
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      setData(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [url]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setOrderNumber(event.target.value);
    //console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(orderNumber);
  }

  const handleUpdate = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Event ID : ${event.target.id}`);
    console.log(input);
    axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/event/${event.target.id}` , input)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          alert("Comment Successfully Updated!")
        } else Promise.reject();
      })
      .catch((err) => alert(`Something went wrong : ${err}`));
    }

  return(
    <div>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        Order Number: <input placeholder="Order Number" type="text" id="message" name="message" onChange={handleChange} value={orderNumber} autoComplete="off" />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
                {data.map((alldata) => (
                    <div key={alldata.ID}> 
                    <input id={alldata.ID} defaultValue={alldata.cmt} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/> 
                    <button id={alldata.ID} onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
                    </div>
                ))} 
                
    </div>
)
}

export default App;
```

Following figure is what data I'm sending via POSTMAN request and it's sending me back 200OK response while the database really get's updated.
[image]

And this is what I'm sending via the front-end user inputs while no errors popped up and the same 200OK response getting from Network tab in browser. But here the database only get's updated as "NULL" no matter what is the user input is.
[image]

[image]

Comment: you should post your backend code, since you claim the issue is in the backend somewhere

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors at all on the development console?  On the network tab is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  If everything client-side is working as expected, what exactly are you asking us about the code shown?

Comment: @Shivam sorry I forgot to mention that the backend code is 100% working as my expectations, I've tested all the routes with POSTMAN and REST Server in VS Code. My issue is if the comment is updating(PUT Endpoint) via POSTMAN and all why it's not working via React front end?

Comment: @Glenn94: When testing the operation in Postman, how specifically are you including the data to send to the server?  What is the content type and where/how do you enter the data?

Comment: @David you really opened some of the blind side, so I never checked the server response and now it clearly gave me the error. Now while the error is not there in the server response, there is a different issue haha, whatever I try to update it's updating as "NULL" in the Database.

Comment: @Glenn94: Same debugging steps.  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what data is included in the AJAX request?  In your "working" Postman request, what data are you sending to the server?  If your claim is that the Postman request works but this request doesn't then your goal is to determine the differences between those requests.

Comment: @David I just added a screenshot of that Network Tab, It's showing me a 200ok response but the all I see is "NULL" in the comment column in the Database.

Comment: @Glenn94: And *what data are you sending in that request*?  And *how are you sending your data in Postman*?  Don't assume.  Observe.  Show that information in the question.

Comment: @David I just added few more detailed figures, and explained the question little better, I feel like something is wrong in my react code, cause I'm submitting the same inputs in both methods (POSTMAN vs React page) but only POSTMAN get's success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the data you send in Postman:

```
{
  "cmt": "Testing Comment"
}
```

But where is this `cmt` property in your JavaScript code?  This is where you're sending the request to the server:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/event/${event.target.id}` , input)
```

And `input` is just a string.  So you're not sending an object at all, you're just sending a string.

Your server-side code should *probably* be validating input before making data changes and returning a successful response.  So I'd argue that this is a problem in *both* the client-side code *and* the server-side code.

But if you're intending to send an *object*, send an object:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/event/${event.target.id}`, { cmt: input })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help sir! It really worked. It was that one simple mistake, couldn't add {cmt : input} but instead I added {input}.